# mongodb only connect by localhost

Tags: mongodb, database-connection

OS: Centos 7
mongodb: v3.6.4
question: just can connect by localhost or 127.0.0.1, if add --host hostIp(like 192.168.1.1), will be connection refuse.
error code:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.6.4
connecting to: mongodb://IP:53082/
2018-06-07T07:57:46.310+0800 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to IP:53082, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-06-07T07:57:46.311+0800 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server IP:53082, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

so, how to resolve this error? please

Comment: BTW the default port for MongoDB is `27017` and unless you actually changed that in the server settings then that's the port you need to use. And if you don't know what "server settings" are, then that's the root of your problem, and hence the linked duplicate.

Comment: i'am sorry for the port `27017` and i actually changed that. but according to the recommend link, i resolved this problem.

i changed the `/etc/mongod.conf` and add bind_ip=0.0.0.0 and restart the mongodb server.  but i don't know why when i set bind_ip=myHostIp  would cause a error for start the mongodb server

Comment: I know there is a tendency to "obfuscate for security purposes" quite often in post. however this is really not the sort of thing you should be obfuscating and you really should be "showing what you are doing" instead of typing in something else. Nonetheless it "looked like" a `bind_ip` issue, and glad it was resolved that way. But please be aware of the "fine line" between "security" and making your intent "totally unclear" by changing such details when asking in the future. Also any "further" questions about "server configuration" go to [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com)